# Radio buttons are before the amounts and on a different line

Tags: civicontribute, forms, fields

How do I make the radio button appear on the same line as the amount/label and on the right of the label? 
I have a simple contribution page - Joomla 3.6.2 and CIVI 4.7.9. The section with amounts to donate starts with a radio button on one line, then the field label is on the next line, then the amount. It makes it confusing as to which button is for which amount.

Comment: Johnny, if the contribution page is public, it would be useful to add a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

CiviCRM should have those radio elements on the same line by default. My guess then is that the website theme or some other module/extension in place alters this behaviour.

This is really a CSS question, and since you're already not seeing the default appearance of CiviCRM forms (see [Drupal](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1), [Joomla!](http://sandbox.joomla.civicrm.org/index.php/component/civicrm/?task=civicrm/contribute/transact&id=1&action=preview&reset=1), [WordPress](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/contribution-page/) examples), your question is likely going to be better solved in two steps:

- *"How do I make my site theme display CiviCRM's form styling as expected?"*, then
- *"How do I change the CSS to position the radio buttons to the right of the label?"*

To do that, you'll need to either give the URL of your site (so people can see for themselves) or describe enough about the CSS in place to let people give you an informed reply.

One thing you could try is switching to a default theme for your CMS and verify if the CiviCRM forms appear as expected. Then you have a reference point for what works, and you can start addressing the issue.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Chris thanks for taking the time to provide an answer.

Comment: I'm giving up on stackexchange as a useful place to resolve problems.

Comment: That would be a shame, as the answer offered here strikes me as a good one, and offers clear guidance about how you can resolve the issue that you reported.